# php mysql html tags

Tags: php, mysql, html, string, tinymce

I am having some trouble with strings which I get from my database.  These strings include various html tags in them as well.  For example:

```
"<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard</p>"
```

This is what I get from the database. How do I get rid of the `<p>` tags in it?  I have already tried `strip_tags` and other functions to no avail.

These tags do not show up in the `tinymce` `textareas` and the tags work there respective functionalities.

Comment: Are the tags escaped? They are escaped when they are visible in your normal HTML output, and not parsed as tags.

Comment: You say that you want to get rid of the tags. In the next sentence you say that the tags dont show up. Explain please?

Comment: Pretty sure `strip_tags` works for removing tags :S Please show us the code that doesn't work and tell us what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function it will help you

```
function convertSpecialChars($string) {
    $string = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $string);
    $string = str_replace("\n", "&#xA;", $string);
    $string = str_replace("‘", "&apos;", $string);
    $string = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $string);
    $string = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $string);
    $string = str_replace("“", "&quot;", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

enjoy...

Comment: this has helped a lot

now i use this
$text = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $string);
$text = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $text);
echo $strip_tags($text); and it has worked. Thankx alot sir

Answer (score 2):

[strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) if you want to remove HTML and PHP tags.

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if you want to keep HTML tags, but remove XSS possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If I understod you correctly, you want to apply [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: i tried this as well. it does convert the tags,outputs '&lt;p&gt;' in place of the tags.. which means htmlentities reads the tags but strip slashes does not.

Comment: @Hammad: Maybe you could tell us what output you expect using some concrete desired result to your example?

Comment: @marc.. i wanted the output to be the simple text within the tags/ or simply the whole text without the html tags etc.. sorry if i sounded confused. thankx a lot though